# How to dynamically display links in web pages using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Good day @ all.
I've this code snippet which's aim is to display the Exam this user is qualified to take based on the courses registered for. It would display the Exam Name, Date Available, Passing Grade and either Take Exam link if he/she hasn't written or View Result if he/she has written previously.

```
/*Connection String */
global $con;

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; //user id

$courses = parse_course($user_id); //parse course gets the list of registered courses (Course Codes) in an array

foreach ($courses as $list)
{
    $written = false;
    $list = parse_course_id($list); //parse_course_id gets the id for each course
    $ers = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from exams where course_id = '$list'");
    while ($erows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ers)) {
        $trs = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from result_data where user_id = '$user_id'");
        while ($trows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trs)) {
            if ($trows['user_id'] == $user_id && $trows['exam_id'] == $erows['exam_id'])
                $written = true;
            else
                $written = false;
        }

        if($written)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".$erows['exam_name']."</td><td>".$erows['exam_from']." To ".$erows['exam_to']."</td><td>".$erows['passing_grade']."%</td><td><a href=proc_result.php?id=".$erows['exam_id'].">".'View Result   '."</a></td></tr>";
            $written = false;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".$erows['exam_name']."</td><td>".$erows['exam_from']." To ".$erows['exam_to']."</td><td>".$erows['passing_grade']."%</td><td><a href=Exam3.php?id=".$erows['exam_id'].">".'Take Exam   '."</a></td></tr>";
            $written = false;
        }

    }

}
```

But It only displays one View Result entry even if I've taken more than one exam. It shows the recent entry. Please what am I missing?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Point take. I'll change that immediately. Thanks @tadman.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're comparing the row's `user_id` column to your `$user_id` variable given that you specifically request only rows for that value in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I feel like those two queries should be JOINed, then the php to follow can be much simpler/cleaner.

Comment: I've edited the query based on your suggestion. However, I'm still new to PHP and MySQL so I don't know how to implement the join. But the result output is still the same. It only displays the recent exam I took and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but here's how I would do it.

I've assumed $user_id is an integer.  I'm a bit worried about it being used in SQL without any sanitization.  I can't guarantee anything else you're doing is secure either because I can't see your other code.  Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

(Oh I see someone already commented on that - don't take it lightly!)

Anyway, my approach would be to collect the user's written exam IDs into an array first.  Then loop through the available exams and check each exam id to see if it's in the array we made earlier.

I wouldn't bother looking into the join advice unless you find this is performing poorly.  In many systems it would be common to have 3 functions in this situation, one that generates $users_written_exam_ids ones that pulls up something like $all_available_exams and then this code which compares the two.   But because people are seeing both queries here together there is a strong temptation to optimize it, which is cool but you probably just want it to work :)

```
<?php
global $con;

// Get the user id.  Pass through intval() so no SQL injection is possible.
$user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);

// Parse course gets the list of registered courses (Course Codes) in an array
$courses = parse_course($user_id); 

foreach ($courses as $list)
{
    // Gets the id for each course
    $list = parse_course_id($list);

    $users_written_exam_ids = array();
    $trs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT exam_id FROM result_data WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
    while ($trows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($trs)) 
    {
        $users_written_exam_ids[] = $trows['exam_id'];
    }

    $ers = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM exams WHERE course_id = '$list'");
    while ($erows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ers)) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $erows['exam_name'] . '</td><td>' . $erows['exam_from'] 
            . ' To ' . $erows['exam_to'] . '</td><td>' . $erows['passing_grade'] 
            . '%</td><td>';
        if (in_array($erows['exam_id'], $users_written_exam_ids))
        {
            echo '<a href="proc_result.php?id=' . $erows['exam_id'] . '">View Result</a>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<a href="Exam3.php?id=' . $erows['exam_id'] . '">Take Exam</a>';
        }
        echo '</td></tr>';

    }

}
```

Comment: In fact if you want to be all pro, do put it into 3 functions, put the functions that pull data from the database into an include file, and don't mix code that does database queries with code that does HTML output.  Something to think about.  That way you can reuse the database functions in other areas of your website :)  You could pass parameters into the functions to restrict them by user ids, exam id, etc... whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks  @ Braks. It works, though I had to change the <$users_written_exam_ids = [];> to <$users_written_exam_ids = array();>. It works perfectly after. I've been going about it the wrong way. I still have a long way to go in mastering this. Thanks to everyone that commented/viewed this.